# VLOOKUP in Excel - find date within range and return associated value

Tags: excel-2013

I have two tabs, one contains my data to include the columns below; the other is a list of values.  I want to have the Week # column to a VLOOKUP to check Date Received and return the Week #, as shown in the second set of values

```
Date 
Received    Week #
12/10/14    1
12/15/14    2
12/15/14    2

Week Start  Week End    Week #
12/08/14    12/12/14    1
12/15/14    12/19/14    2
12/22/14    12/26/14    3
12/29/14    01/02/15    4
```

Comment: You would help yourself better if you read up on the VLOOKUP function and tried a few commands and then revert back here if you are still stuck

Answer (score 0):

The sample may be too small, but on its basis if `Received` is in A2:

```
=WEEKNUM(A3)-49
```

in B3 and copied down to suit may be adequate.